# I was trying to complete a palindrome-check but reverse variable is not having the expected value

Tags: python

The following code should perform a check if the number provided by a user is palindrome or not, but the code in while loop reverse is always not equal to the number even when I enter `12321` as a value.

```
number=input("Type the number:")

temp=number
reverse=0
reminder=0

while temp!=0 :
      reminder=int(temp)%10
      reverse=reverse*10+reminder
      temp=int(temp)/10    

if reverse==number :
      print("this is a palindrome number")
else:
      print("this is not a palindrome number")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with small hacks: string representation of number and iterating with negative indices:

```
def is_palindrome(num):
    string = str(num)
    for i, e in enumerate(string):
        if e != string[-1 * (i+1)]:
            return False
    return True

is_palindrome(12344321)
```

> `True`

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work. Any input entered is always a string. While comparing the result with the input number, convert it to int. Also do floor division ("//").

```
number = input("Type the number:")


temp = int(number)
reverse = 0
reminder = 0

while temp != 0:
    reminder = temp % 10
    reverse = reverse*10+reminder
    print(reverse)
    temp = temp//10

if reverse == int(number):
    print("this is a palindrome number")
else:
    print("this is not a palindrome number")
```

If you want a slightly better solution than all the dividing thing. Then the below code should work.

```
number = input("Type the number:")

if number.isdigit():
    if number == number[::-1]:
        print('this is a palindrome number')
    else:
        print('this is not a palindrome number')
else:
    print('Input entered is not a number')
```

Answer (score 0):

> for floor division, use "//"

```
number=int(input("Type the number:"))


temp=number
reverse=0
reminder=0

while temp!=0 :
      reminder=temp%10
      reverse=reverse*10+reminder
      temp=temp//10 # <-------
      # or u can use  
      # temp=int(temp/10) # <-------
if reverse==number :
      print("this is a palindrome number")
else:
      print("this is not a palindrome number")
```

> **// floor division**
>
> *Description:*
>
> Returns the integral part of the quotient.
>
> *Syntax:*
>
> ```
> A // B
> ```
>
> A: Any expression evaluating to a numeric type.
>
> B: Any expression evaluating to a numeric type.
>
> *Return Value:*
>
> According to coercion rules.
>
> *Remarks:*
>
> Also referred to as integer division. The resultant value is a whole
>   integer, though the result’s type is not necessarily int.
>
> *Example:*
>
> ```
> >>> 5.0 / 2
> 2.5
> >>> 5.0 // 2
> 2.0
> ```

.

> **NOTE:**
>
> In Python 3.0, 5 / 2 will return 2.5 and 5 // 2 will return 2. The
>   former is floating point division, and the latter is floor division,
>   sometimes also called integer division.
>
> In Python 2.2 or later in the 2.x line, there is no difference for
>   integers unless you perform a from **future** import division, which
>   causes Python 2.x to adopt the behavior of 3.0
>
> Regardless of the future import, 5.0 // 2 will return 2.0 since that's
>   the floor division result of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

i would change the line for the temp
temp=int(int(temp)/10)
and I would also ask whether int(number)== int(reverse)

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to check in python if a number is palindrome

```
number = input("Type the number:")
temp = str(number)
reverse = temp[::-1]

if reverse == temp :
    print("this is a palindrome number")
else:
    print("this is not a palindrome number")
```